# storyboard and apple recommendations

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5

im starting a new project now and I would like to build it with nibs and not with storyboard, apple removed the option in xcode 5 to build an app without storyboard, my question is that is there any recommendations by apple that developers should develop with storyboard and other xib files will not be allowed in the future? or its ok and apple will always support nib files without storyboard projects and allow it to be submitted in the future

thanks

Comment: Apple did not remove the option to build app without storyboard in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 1):

Apple certainly seem to be pushing people to use Storyboards, but there's nothing to stop you removing Storyboards from a project and just using Xibs. I only use Storyboards sometimes, occasionally use Xibs, and often write entire apps programmatically (no Xibs or Storyboards at all). There are a number of important use cases which are only possible using Xibs, so they won't be going anywhere any time soon.

The only change Apple made was that project templates always include a Storyboard - but you can still remove it once you've created a new project.